# Taking a set of items from a list and to perform some operation based on need

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items in a list. From that list I need to take the first 1000 items and need to submit the package and then again I need to take another 1000 and need to submit a package. If the list is not having 1000 I need to submit the package with all the items. for that I wrote the following code which is returning an error as collection modified.

```
List<SyncQueue> tempMassiveSyncQueue=massiveSyncQueue;
while (tempMassiveSyncQueue.Count != 0)
{
    int MassivePackageFileCount =Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MassivePackageFileLimit"]);
     massiveSyncQueues = tempMassiveSyncQueue;
    List<SyncQueue> tempMassivePackageSyncQueue=new List<SyncQueue>();
     if (massiveSyncQueues.Count > 1000
     {
         var massivePackageSyncQueue = (massiveSyncQueues.Take(1000)).ToList<SyncQueue>();
         tempMassivePackageSyncQueue = massivePackageSyncQueue;

         SubmitPackage(massivePackageSyncQueue);
     }

     if (tempMassivePackageSyncQueue.Count != 0)
     {
         foreach (var massivesynq in tempMassiveSyncQueue)
         {
             foreach (var deleteId in tempMassivePackageSyncQueue.Where(id => id.SyncQueueId == massivesynq.SyncQueueId))
             {
                 tempMassiveSyncQueue.Remove(massivesynq);
             }
         }
     }


     else
     {
         SubmitPackage(massiveSyncQueues);

     }
    massiveSyncQueues = null;
}
```

Can any one help on this?

Comment: "returning an error" what error does it return?

Comment: "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute". this is the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporate Skip into your logic

```
int loopCount = 0;
While(true)
{
    var ListToProcess = massiveSyncQueue.Skip(loopCount*1000).Take(1000);

    SubmitPackage(ListToProcess);

    if(ListToProcess.Count < 1000)   // We know there are no more in the list massive list.
    {
        break;
    }
    loopCnt++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are adjusting the collection on which the bounds of the foreach construct are set.

Try using ToList() on the collection you are looping through, as this creates a new List in memory:

```
    foreach (var massivesynq in tempMassiveSyncQueue.ToList())
{
    foreach (var deleteId in tempMassivePackageSyncQueue.Where(id => id.SyncQueueId == massivesynq.SyncQueueId).ToList())
    {
        tempMassiveSyncQueue.Remove(massivesynq);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 1 you set tempMassiveSyncQueue = massiveSyncQueue, yet within the while loop you set massiveSyncQueue = tempMassiveSync.

The collection modified error usually occurs when you modify the collection you are looping through. Which is why you need to first create a copy of the collection which is INDEPENDANT to the original collection and loop through that.

Before the while loop you need to add all items in massiveSyncQueue to tempMassiveSyncQueue. You then need to loop through the temp list with your code. In the second loop, you are removing items from the list you are looping through. I assume you meant to remove the items from massiveSyncQueue and not the temp list.

Try the following:

```
List<SyncQueue> tempMassiveSyncQueue = new List<SyncQueue>();
foreach(var item in massiveSyncQueue)
{
   tempMassiveSyncQueue.Add(item);
}
while (tempMassiveSyncQueue.Count != 0)
{
int MassivePackageFileCount = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MassivePackageFileLimit"]);
List<SyncQueue> tempMassivePackageSyncQueue=new List<SyncQueue>();
 if (massiveSyncQueues.Count > 1000
 {
     var massivePackageSyncQueue = (massiveSyncQueues.Take(1000)).ToList<SyncQueue>();
     tempMassivePackageSyncQueue = massivePackageSyncQueue;

     SubmitPackage(massivePackageSyncQueue);
 }

 if (tempMassivePackageSyncQueue.Count != 0)
 {
     foreach (var massivesynq in massiveSyncQueue)
     {
         foreach (var deleteId in tempMassivePackageSyncQueue.Where(id => id.SyncQueueId == massivesynq.SyncQueueId))
         {
             massiveSyncQueue.Remove(massivesynq);
         }
     }
 }


 else
 {
     SubmitPackage(massiveSyncQueues);

 }
massiveSyncQueues = null;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int count=1;
while(tempMassivePackageSyncQueue.Count>1000)
{


    var massivePackageSyncQueue = (massiveSyncQueues.skip(count*1000).Take(1000)).ToList<SyncQueue>();
         tempMassivePackageSyncQueue = massivePackageSyncQueue;

         SubmitPackage(massivePackageSyncQueue);
    count++;

}
var massivePackageSyncQueue = (massiveSyncQueues.skip(count*1000).Take()).ToList<SyncQueue>();
         tempMassivePackageSyncQueue = massivePackageSyncQueue;

         SubmitPackage(massivePackageSyncQueue);
```